# Standard way to embed newlines into xml

Tags: xml, newline

I have some xml like this:

```
<animal name="Bow Wow" type="dog">
    <birthDate>May 17,2001</birthDate>
    <descirption>Bla bla bla bla</description>
</animal>
```

The xml is being processed and displayed on the screen.

I need to provide a longer multi-paragraph description of the dog but I am running into some problems.

If I write my xml like this:

```
<animal name="Bow Wow" type="dog">
    <birthDate>May 17,2001</birthDate>
    <descirption>
          p1: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

          p2: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

          p3: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    </description>
</animal>
```

Then when the xml is printed to the screen it is printed like this:

```
              p1: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

              p2: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

              p3: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

I would like the description to be printed like this (without the leading tabs):

```
p1: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

p2: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

p3: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

Is there a reasonable solution to this problem?  I was thinking that one thing I could do would be to put all the text on one line like this:

```
    <descirption>p1: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <NEWLINE/>NEWLINE/>p2: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla<NEWLINE/>NEWLINE/>p3: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</description>
```

I am not sure if there is a standard xml new line tag though.  I know that you can encode an `&` with & is there something like this for new line?  Is there a standard way to deal with this issue?

Comment: you could use a `CDATA` wrapper around your text.

Comment: What are you processing the xml with?  In PHP, for instance, you could use the [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to clean off the whitespace from the beginning and end.

Comment: @Surreal, I could do that but I would much rather change the xml rather than the code reading it.

Comment: why bother ? is meant for machine to read, human only read the rendered results

Comment: @ajreal, I have to read the xml and will be editing it for the next couple days.  I would like to keep it in some way that I can navigate it reasonably easily.  I am using vim to edit it and using indentation for folding.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude - tons of free xml editor ... none of these free tools fit your feet?

Comment: @ajreal, I like vim and it fits all of my requirements however I need to maintain the correct indentation.

Comment: I like driving, but I don't have $ to buy a car ... what shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML whitespace handling is a big problem. Your DOM will have settable options which affect how it works, but the upshot is:

The easiest way to solve the problem is to ignore whitespace and use a tag of your own make. I use `<br />` for newlines, then convert them to CRLF for display.

If using XSLT you will need to make use of `<xsl:text>` tags wherever you need text to make sure whitespace is handled how you want.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the description to be printed like this (without the leading tabs)

Remove the leading tabs from your source

```
<animal name="Bow Wow" type="dog">
    <birthDate>May 17,2001</birthDate>
    <descirption>
p1: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

p2: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

p3: Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    </description>
</animal>
```

Comment: I thought about doing that but it makes my xml document very hard to read.